# A custom domain object isn't being shown while using @ModelAttribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger, springfox

I am using Springfox and Swagger to generate swagger files. Right now I'm using `@ModelAttribute` to pull the variables from an object (`NetworkCmd`) to show as query params in the swagger doc.

I currently have the following controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{product_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseHeader()
public ResponseEntity<?> networkResponse(
    @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers,
    @PathVariable("product_id")String productId,
    @Valid @ModelAttribute NetworkCmd cmd,
    BindingResult result)
    throws Exception {

    ...
}
```

And here is a sample of `NetworkCmd`:

```
@ItemId
@NotNull(message = "product cannot be null")
@ApiModelProperty(
    value = "testing")
private String product_id;

@ApiModelProperty(
    value = "key",
private String key;

@ApiModelProperty(
    value = "parent")
private Boolean is_parent_id;

@Min(0)
@ApiModelProperty(
    value = "radius")
private double radius = 10d;
```

One of the variables in this class is a custom domain object `Nearby`.

```
private Nearby nearby = null;

public Nearby getNearby() {
    return nearby;
}

public void setNearby(String nearby) throws ParseException {
    this.nearby = Nearby.parse(nearby);
}
```

This is kind of a special variable because it takes in a String, and then parses that string and turns it into the `Nearby` object.

My problem is that this `Nearby` variable isn't showing up on the generated swagger document through `@ModelAttribute`. I'm happy to provide any more information.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get around this problem is to create an alternate type rule in your docket. This way anytime we encounter the nearby type we treat it as a string.

```
new Docket(...)
     .directModelSubstitute(Nearby.class, String.class)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I've also tried:

`.directModelSubstitute(Nearby.class, Object.class)`